# What is the difference between temporal logic and Dialectical Logic (Hegel)?

Tags: logic, aristotle, hegel

I have been reading Hegel's Science of Logic where he critiques its generation understanding of logic known as Formal Logic.

As I have come to understand one of the main differences between Hegel's understanding of logic and the understanding he was critiquing was that of time and change.

But yesterday I come upon [(in this question)](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/97546/70653) the type of Logic called Temporal Logic as an extension of Aristotelian Logic. So now I'm confused.

What is the difference between Temporal Logic and the Logic presented by Hegel?

Comment: Can you cite where you read that Aristotle wrote about temporal logic? I find that rather implausible.

Comment: Hegel's Science of Logic is **not** formal logic, while A's Syllogistic is.

Answer (score 0):

I think the entries on SEP can answer your question better than I can:

> “Hegel’s dialectics” refers to the particular dialectical method of argument employed by the 19th Century German philosopher, G.W.F. Hegel (see entry on Hegel), which, like other “dialectical” methods, relies on a contradictory process between opposing sides. Whereas Plato’s “opposing sides” were people (Socrates and his interlocutors), however, what the “opposing sides” are in Hegel’s work depends on the subject matter he discusses.

> The term Temporal Logic has been broadly used to cover all approaches to reasoning about time and temporal information, as well as their formal representation, within a logical framework, and also more narrowly to refer specifically to the modal-logic type of approach introduced around 1960 by Arthur Prior under the name Tense Logic and subsequently developed further by many logicians and computer scientists.

The differences here are that Dialectical logic is principally concerned with analysis via appraisal of contradictory processes between opposing sides. Temporal or tense logic is logic *about* time. For example, "no event precedes itself". Tense logic is a formal logic *about time*.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hegel-dialectics/
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-temporal/

Answer (score 0):

No, Hegel isn't concerned with time and change in his *Logic* at all. You might be confused by the term 'moment': but it doesn't denote a temporal moment, only a moment in sense of an *aspect*, a *side*.